# Creating a streaming conference between a client and a bot using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'd like to create a conference between a client (real phone number) and a virtual agent (bot).
The whole conference or just the client's leg should be streamed (using the new Stream TwiML verb).

The stream from the client will be analyzed and used to respond to the client through the Say TwiML verb after some analysis.

My question is how do I initiate such a conference where the client has a stream?

I would expect something along these lines but can't quite figure it out:

```
    # Bot participant
    bot_participant = client.conferences(f'{patient_id}_{scheduler_id}') \
        .participants.create(from_=phone_from, to=VIRTUAL_NUMBER)
    print(bot_participant)

    # Patient participant
    patient_participant = client.conferences(f'{patient_id}_{scheduler_id}') \
        .participants.create(from_=phone_from, to=phone_to, stream_url='wss://...')
    print(patient_participant)
```

Answer (score 0):

Leo, for media streams, you currently need to have TwiML returned. The [Agent Conference Add Participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only) feature adds the participant directly to the conference without referencing external TwiML, so that will not work.

Instead, dial the party you want to add to the conference using the [Calls Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource), then return TwiML which uses the [Stream TwiML verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream) and then [Dials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) into the conference.

Comment: what if my conference is generated through a task router assignment event? how can I attach a stream?